# Difference between recently and since

Tags: tenses

*"I have recently joined this company and I have been working here for 3 months."*
Is this sentence grammatically correct? If I use recently then is it correct to specify the time stamp like 3 months?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but 'recently' is vague and can mean different time periods depending upon context and individual interpretation. Since you specify that you have been working there for 3 months, there is little point in mentioning that this is recent. It is not incorrect, but superfluous.

Of course, you might have joined the company years ago, and only just started working where you are 3 months ago, which is different.